# How to redirect 162 port to a customized port which above 1024 for snmp trap?

Tags: linux, permissions, snmp, iptables, privileges

I wrote some pieces of code to listen on 162 port. It looks like following

```
listenAddress = GenericAddress.parse(System.getProperty("snmp4j.listenAddress", "udp:0.0.0.0/162"));
TransportMapping transport;
if (listenAddress instanceof UdpAddress) {
    transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping((UdpAddress) listenAddress);
} else {
    transport = new DefaultTcpTransportMapping((TcpAddress) listenAddress);
}
snmp = new Snmp(dispatcher, transport);
snmp.getMessageDispatcher().addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv2c());
snmp.listen();
```

But the code just can be started by non-root user. So when I run program, I got an error. `java.net.bindexception permission denied.`

I would like to redirect 162 port to 16200. And in my code, I can call it like this

```
listenAddress = GenericAddress.parse(System.getProperty("snmp4j.listenAddress", "udp:0.0.0.0/16200"));
```

Then I modified /etc/sysconfig/iptables, but it didn`t work. Following is iptables configuration.

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1379:235423]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [6:680]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6:680]
-A PREROUTING -p udp  -m udp --dport 162 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 16200
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Nov 10 18:07:25 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Thu Nov 10 18:07:25 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [38534:3129869]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2052:284032]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 161 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 161 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 162 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 162 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 161 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 161 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 162 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 162 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 16200 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 16200 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 161 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 161 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 162 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 162 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 161 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 161 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 162 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 162 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 16200 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 16200 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Nov 10 18:07:25 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Thu Nov 10 18:07:25 2016
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [39240:3206748]
:INPUT ACCEPT [38535:3129909]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2052:284032]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2052:284032]
COMMIT
```

How to configure iptables so I can get trap message on 16200 port? Or is there any other methods to do this?

I am confused. Please give me some suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure iptables properly to forward all incoming UDP packets from port `162` to user defined port (`>1024`).

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s3 -p udp --dport 162 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5678
```

You should replace the `enp0s3` with proper network interface name. Use ifconfig to find out the name of your Ethernet interface. Usually - `eth0`. In this example all incoming UDP packets from port `162` will be forwarded to UDP port `5678`.

Comment: Yes, In my test environment, everything is OK. But in my usr`s environment which is the Double Network Card Binding, it doesn`t work. I think I should add "-i bound0" for iptables command. I will try it next week when usr`s environment available.